# How to use jquery Cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, browser

I have simple code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {    
                $('.close_i').click(function(){
                    $('.adsbox').hide();
                    $('.open_i').show();
                });

                $('.open_i').click(function(){
                    $('.adsbox').show();
                    $('.open_i').hide();
                });    
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="adsbox">
            <img src="as1.jpg">
            <img src="as2.jpg">
            <img src="as3.jpg">
            <img src="as4.jpg">
            <img src="as5.jpg">
            <img src="as6.jpg">
           <a class="close_i">Close ADS</a>
       </div>

       <a class="open_i" style="display:none;">Open ADS</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want this:
when a user clicks on the "Close ADS", there are the following jQuery instructions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('.close_i').click(function(){
        $('.adsbox').hide();
        $('.open_i').show();
    });

    $('.open_i').click(function(){
        $('.adsbox').show();
        $('.open_i').hide();
    });    
});
```

and cookie plugin, save the adsbox status in the user's browser for 3 days.

My question is: How can I use  jQuery Cookie  ?! **i dont know this explanation :
 [jquery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).**

Can you give me some working code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('.close_i').click(function(){
        $('.adsbox').hide();
        $('.open_i').show();
        $.cookie("Disclaimer", 1, { expires : 3 });
    });

    $('.open_i').click(function(){
        $('.adsbox').show();
        $('.open_i').hide();
        $.removeCookie("Disclaimer");
    });    
});
```

If he closed the adds, whenever he enter the page again the adds must be closed (3 days from now on), so you have to add this also:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    if ($.cookie("Disclaimer")){
        $('.adsbox').hide();
        $('.open_i').show();
    });   
});
```